# error as - "cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'" on AWS Lambda using a layer

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-requests, boto3, urllib3

for python 3.9,imported libraries "boto3_version": "1.26.90", "botocore_version": "1.29.90", "urllib3": "1.26.11". Fetch data from public api but when attaching 'requests' library having version as 2.29.0 in aws lambda layers for lambda function it gives error as - No module named 'requests'.
For latest requests version if uploading it is working but adding boto3 library in layer part, it is giving error as - "cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'" on AWS Lambda using a layer.URL - 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Bangalore,IND&APPID=53d6430c1eccacb54e827045d1aee3d3'
Please reply

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import urllib3
import csv
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# from botocore.vendored import requests
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
today = datetime.today()  
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'rawlake'
    URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/REPLACE URL'
    response = requests.get(URL)
    response = response.json()
```

posted an error which I am facing issue .I am expecting correct answer solved ones as soon as possible.